# Uniform Distribution Algorithm On A Shape

Tags: c#, algorithm, distribution, division

I'm having difficulty formulating this elegantly into an algorithm.

So I have a given a straight-edged shape (ie. square, though in the end shape doesn't matter only endpoints).  I get the bounding endpoints on a Cartesian coordinate system :  (2,-2) (2,2) (-2,2) (-2,-2)

I'm given an arbitrary number of points (ie. 7) and I want to spread these points (x,y) uniformly along the edges of the shape (in this case a square).

My current idea is to get the total length of all endpoints, divide this by the number of points to get a segment length (which I then normalize against an edge). Then I go from endpoint to endpoint finding the point between by this amount and accrue the normalized slice, when this total exceeds 1.0 I iterate the endpoint and take the remainder and start from there...or something like that.

Could someone help me put this into an algorithm (C# preferably) or if you have a better solution please do tell.  I'd imagine there is a sorting or distribution/division algorithm that could have the same affect, but I couldn't find any.  I hope this isn't blatantly obvious.

Comment: Uniform in what sense?  Arc length measure?

Comment: evenly spaced in regard to straight line paths, I have a separate algorithm for handling arc length and circles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How general does this need to be? Also, how are representing your shape, and the points? Your algorithm seems to be ok; do you need help turning it into code?

---

Alrighty, here's something i came up with.
Notes on the code:

- The distance method takes two Points and returns the distance between them.
- The normalize method takes two points and returns the normal vector pointing from the first point to the second point.
- The Point class has the multiply method which multiplies the point by a scalar
- The Point class has float (or double) precision

I'm using the Point class to represent vectors by the way.

I haven't tested this, so there might be bugs. There might be issues with how this algorithm handles exact regions (e.g. your square with exactly 4 points on it). Let me know if there are issues or if you have any questions! :)

```
Point[] shapePoints; //already initialized
int numPoints; //already initialized
Point[] retPoints = new Point[numPoints];
int totalLength;
for(int i = 1; i < shapePoints.length; i++){
    totalLength += distance(shapePoints[i], (shapePoints[i-1]));
}
float segLength = ((float) totalLength) / numPoints);
Point currShape = shapePoints[0];
Point nextShape = shapePoints[1];
Point prev = currShape;
int counter = 2;
while(numPoints > 0){
    Point norm = normalize(new Point(nextShape.x - currShape.x, nextShape.y - currShape.y));
    if(distance(nextShape, prev) < segLength){
        int tempLength = segLength;
        tempLength -= distance(nextShape, prev);
        currShape = nextShape;
        nextShape = shapePoints[counter];
        counter ++;
        norm = normalize(new Point(nextShape.x - currShape.x, nextShape.y - currShape.y));
        norm.multiply(tempLength);
    }
    else{
        norm.multiply(segLength);
    }       
    retPoints[numPoints - 1] = norm;
    prev = retPoints[numPoints - 1];
    numPoints --;
}
```

---

```
Point normalize(Point p){
    int scale = Math.sqrt(p.x * p.x + p.y * p.y);
    p.x = p.x / scale;
    p.y = p.y / scale;
    return p;
}
```

Comment: well for now all I want to get are the points (x,y).  It's pretty general, as the (straight-line) shape makes no difference. I really only deal with the endpoints. And yes, I'm having trouble turning it into code elegantly =)

Comment: Ok. I'm writing something right now :) should be done fairly soon.

Comment: what would be the implementation for normalize?

Comment: norms seems to repeat the value (0,8), not sure if that's some fault of my own yet.  But I believe the fundamentals are all there and I can take it the rest of the way, I'm going to consider this answered.  Thank you again!

Comment: Try and debug it on your own. If you have questions about how the algorithm works, leave a comment and I'll reply to it.